# Is this the right approach to handle additional content for android apps?

Tags: android, add-on

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best practice for unlocking app features to the user in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247222/what-is-the-best-practice-for-unlocking-app-features-to-the-user-in-android)

How are add-ons for apps handled? 
Let's say I write a game and want to release levels in episodes.

From what I have read here [Google Help-Page on DLC](http://www.google.pl/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=385c062eaa8f9ac2&hl=en), every batch of levels should be an application.
So I guess I have to use the package manager to check if the user has some of them on the device.
The accepted answer of this similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803342/how-to-release-application-plugin-using-android-market), suggests the same thing, but it only covers resources.

So I'm wondering, based on that, if I had not only resources, but actual logic, that I could just use another apk as a sort of 'jar' file for everything?

I have the feeling that this might be the kind of question I should know the answer for by reading the manual, but ...it has eluded me, despite doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The source you linked was from a long time ago.  Nowadays, it's better to use [In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html).  From the source (emphasis mine):

> Android Market In-app Billing is an Android Market service that lets you sell digital content in your applications. You can use the service to sell a wide range of content, including downloadable content such as media files or photos, **and virtual content such as game levels or potions.**